# jqgrid autocomplete reload grid on selection of option

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid-asp.net

I am writing a piece of code, where i have a jqgrid and a filter with a textbox on the top, i have used the jquery ui autocomplete functionality, everything works fine, but i need to customize the functionality now i.e on autocomplete results when i select a option it should filter the grid with the result selected. Following is the example given below:

```
    // i am doing a search on the textbox with auto complete feature
    grid.jqGrid('setColProp', 'Name',
    {
        searchoptions: {
        sopt:['cn'],
        dataInit: function(elem) {
            $(elem).autocomplete({
            source:getUniqueNames('Name'),
            delay:0,
            minLength:0,
            matchContains: true,
            autoFill:true,
            select:function(event,ui){
            grid.setGridParam('postData', ui.item.value);
            //grid.jqGrid('clearGridData');
            grid.trigger('reloadGrid');
            return false;
            // need to write the code which will trigger the reload here on selection
        }
        });
        }
        }
    });
```

On select function i need the selected option to be loaded in the jqgrid, how can i do it. Please suggest solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented server side sorting and paging for your jqgrid then this should be easy, you simply need to reload the jqgrid.

To reload the grid see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201883/jqGrid-Quick-Tips), use this line of code

```
 $("#grid1").trigger("reloadGrid", [{current:true}]);
```

this will reload the jqgrid, where you can pass in the paramters using `postData:` and get the filtered data.